# Error en el login php

Tags: php, mysql, login

Buenos Dias,

Tengo un error al momneto de hacer un login, este es mi codigo:

logout.php

Aqui creo un archivo llamado Salir.php para que realice el cierre de sesión.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();

    header('location: index.php');
?>
```

index.php

Aqui Creo el archivo index.php, el cual contendrá el formulario de login y al mismo tiempo el mensaje de bienvenida o de error.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";

Función verificar_login()
```

Aqui creo una función llamada verificar_login, esta se encargara de hacer una consulta a la base de datos para saber si el usuario ingresado es correcto o no.

```
function verificar_login($user,$password,&$result)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$user' and password='$password'";
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            $count++;
            $result = $row;
        }
        if($count != 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        if(verificar_login($_POST['user'],$_POST['password'],$result) == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $result->idusuario;
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<div class="error">Su usuario es incorrecto, intente nuevamente.</div>';
        }
    }
?>
<form action="" method="post" class="login">
    <div><label>Username</label><input name="user" type="text" ></div>
    <div><label>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></div>
    <div><input name="login" type="submit" value="login"></div>
</form>
<?php
} else {
    echo 'Su usuario ingreso correctamente.';
    echo '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';
}
?>
```

me sale que mi usuario es incorrecto y los datos estan bien ingresados.

Comment: ayuda porfavor.

Comment: Intenta cambiar tu consulta sql a esta:  $sql = "SELECT 'x' FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$user' and password='$password'";

Comment: interesante....

Comment: puede que sea un error al momento de verificar?

Comment: Tengo la intuicion que estas comparando la variable password en claro con la password cifrada en la BBDD

Comment: wow tienen chat, como hablo en el chat??

Comment: Puedes comprobar el valor de $count? Tal como lo tienes planteado, podría tener el valor 2 o más si el usuario y la contraseña se repiten en la bbdd.

Comment: es 1, no se repite ya tengo una validacion que me permite ver si estan repetidas, y cancelarlas.. si se planea crear un usuario igual

Comment: porque no puedo hablar en el chat?

Comment: @JosualProCode la password como esta grabada en BBDD, porque si esta cifrada esa query no va a funcionar nunca.

Comment: aun no esta cifrada, no lahe implementado aun @Lithorell

Comment: Pues cuando la cifres tendras que cambiar el metodo verificar_login.

Comment: mmm oka, bueno tengo que agregar algo mas.... XD

Comment: la posicion de los return 1 y 0 no tiene nada que ver o si?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error esta al momento de hacer la verificacion:

```
function verificar_login($user,$password,&$result)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$user' and password='$password'";
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            $count++;
            $result = $row;
        }
        if($count == 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Tenias colocado `if($count != 1)`por lo tanto eso nunca iba a entrar, espero y te sirva.

Comment: dejame ver a haber

Comment: definitivamente... soy ciego... como no pude ver eso jajaja, Gracias!!!!! te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: me alegro que te haya servido :3 cualquier otra cosa aqui estoy :3

Comment: bueno si si tengo otras preguntas